# Play 2.6 Kamon AspectJ missing error

Tags: playframework, akka, aspectj, kamon, akka-monitoring

I'm facing this issue with kamon integration. Tried various other ways still unable to fix this. I have a sample project which run on these configurations. I must be missing something very simple.

#### Plugin.sbt

```
import sbt.Resolver

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.bintrayIvyRepo("kamon-io", "sbt-plugins")
)
addSbtPlugin("io.kamon" % "sbt-aspectj-play-runner-26" % "1.0.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.7")
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.5.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.1.6")
```

#### build.sbt

```
import sbt.Keys.libraryDependencies

name := """event-publication-service"""
organization := "com.nice.incontact"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val resolutionRepos = Seq("Kamon Repository Snapshots" at "http://snapshots.kamon.io")

val kamonVersion = "0.6.7"
val dependencies = Seq(
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-core" % kamonVersion,
   "io.kamon" %% "kamon-jmx" % kamonVersion,
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-akka-2.5" % kamonVersion,
//  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-play-26" % kamonVersion,
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-akka-http" % kamonVersion,
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-datadog" % kamonVersion
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala, LauncherJarPlugin, JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)
  .settings(resolvers ++= resolutionRepos)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= dependencies)
scalaVersion := "2.12.3"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "com.pauldijou" %% "jwt-play-json" % "0.14.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "amazon-kinesis-client" % "1.8.1" % Compile
libraryDependencies +=  "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" % "jackson-dataformat-cbor" % "2.8.10" % Compile
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.5.0" % Compile
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.uuid" % "java-uuid-generator" % "3.1.4" % Compile
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit_2.12" % "2.5.6" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.pegdown" % "pegdown" % "1.6.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.7.15" % Test

libraryDependencies += "org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % "1.8.6"

fork in run := true

//kamon.aspectj.sbt.AspectjRunner.testSettings

javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application-test.conf"

testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", "TestReports")

coverageEnabled := true
coverageMinimum := 85
coverageFailOnMinimum := true
coverageExcludedPackages := "<empty>;.*javascript.*;Reverse.*;router.*"
coverageExcludedFiles := "Reverse*"

packageName in Docker := packageName.value
maintainer in Docker := "Partner Integration Team"
dockerBaseImage := "java:8-jre"
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(9443)
dockerExposedVolumes := Seq("/opt/docker/logs")
dockerEntrypoint := Seq("bin/event-publication-service", "-Dconfig.file=conf/application-prod.conf", "-Dhttps.port=9443", "-Dhttp.port=disabled")
```

#### OnStartUp

```
[info] Updating {file:/D:/Sprint2/PubSubService/IC2287/}root...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn]  * io.netty:netty-handler:4.0.43.Final is selected over 4.0.41.Final
[warn]      +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.0.43.Final             (depends on 4.0.43.Final)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams:1.0.8    (depends on 4.0.41.Final)
[warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:22.0 is selected over {18.0, 19.0}
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.7                  (depends on 22.0)
[warn]      +- com.google.inject:guice:4.1.0                      (depends on 19.0)
[warn]      +- com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.8.1          (depends on 18.0)
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.6 is selected over 2.4.19
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-streams_2.12:2.6.7          (depends on 2.5.6)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core_2.12:10.0.10      (depends on 2.4.19)
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.6 is selected over {2.5.2, 2.4.14, 2.4.19}
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.6 ()        (depends on 2.5.6)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.7                  (depends on 2.5.6)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.12:2.5.6 ()         (depends on 2.5.6)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing_2.12:10.0.10        (depends on 2.4.19)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-jmx_2.12:0.6.7                      (depends on 2.4.14)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-core_2.12:0.6.7                     (depends on 2.4.14)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-datadog_2.12:0.6.7                  (depends on 2.4.14)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-akka-2.4_2.12:0.6.6                 (depends on 2.4.14)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-akka-2.5_2.12:0.6.7                 (depends on 2.5.2)
[warn]  * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.12:0.8.0 is selected over 0.5.0
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.6 ()         (depends on 0.8.0)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-streams_2.12:2.6.7          (depends on 0.8.0)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.7                  (depends on 0.8.0)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-datadog_2.12:0.6.7                  (depends on 0.5.0)
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings

[info] Running the application with Aspectj Weaver
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 29 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to D:\Sprint2\PubSubService\IC2287\target\scala-2.12\classes ...
[info] [info] Cleaning datadir [D:\Sprint2\PubSubService\IC2287\target\scala-2.12/scoverage-data]
[info] [info] Beginning coverage instrumentation
[info] [info] Instrumentation completed [1215 statements]
[info] [info] Wrote instrumentation file [D:\Sprint2\PubSubService\IC2287\target\scala-2.12\scoverage-data\scoverage.coverage.xml]
[info] [info] Will write measurement data to [D:\Sprint2\PubSubService\IC2287\target\scala-2.12/scoverage-data]
[warn] there were two feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Done compiling.
[info] c.n.i.Application - Initiating configurations
[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[info] c.n.i.s.PubSubSupervisor - Supervisor is started
[info] c.n.i.p.a.EventRouter - EventRouter Actor is created
[info] c.n.i.u.ApplicationUtil - Checking for keys.
[info] c.n.i.t.a.TransformerActor - Transformer created.
[info] c.a.s.k.c.c.KinesisClientLibConfigurator - Value of workerId is not provided in the properties. WorkerId is automatically assigned as: 4905dbb1-2711-40c4-839c-3140086cea44
[info] c.a.s.k.c.c.KinesisClientLibConfigurator - Successfully set property initialPositionInStream with value TRIM_HORIZON
[info] c.n.i.c.KinesisConsumer -
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- Initialising Kinesis Consumer --------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
***** Running event-publication-service-dipjyoti_akka_test *****
***** Processing Stream: dipjyoti_akka_test *****
***** WorkerId: 4905dbb1-2711-40c4-839c-3140086cea44 *****
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[info] k.Kamon$Instance - Initializing Kamon...
[INFO] [01/05/2018 14:22:06.851] [PubSubSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [DatadogExtension(akka://kamon)] Starting the Kamon(Datadog) extension
[error] k.ModuleLoaderExtension -

  ___                           _      ___   _    _                                 ___  ___ _            _
 / _ \                         | |    |_  | | |  | |                                |  \/  |(_)          (_)
/ /_\ \ ___  _ __    ___   ___ | |_     | | | |  | |  ___   __ _ __   __ ___  _ __  | .  . | _  ___  ___  _  _ __    __ _
|  _  |/ __|| '_ \  / _ \ / __|| __|    | | | |/\| | / _ \ / _` |\ \ / // _ \| '__| | |\/| || |/ __|/ __|| || '_ \  / _` |
| | | |\__ \| |_) ||  __/| (__ | |_ /\__/ / \  /\  /|  __/| (_| | \ V /|  __/| |    | |  | || |\__ \\__ \| || | | || (_| |
\_| |_/|___/| .__/  \___| \___| \__|\____/   \/  \/  \___| \__,_|  \_/  \___||_|    \_|  |_/|_||___/|___/|_||_| |_| \__, |
            | |                                                                                                      __/ |
            |_|                                                                                                     |___/

 It seems like your application was not started with the -javaagent:/path-to-aspectj-weaver.jar option but Kamon detected
 the following modules which require AspectJ to work properly:

      kamon-akka, kamon-akka-http, kamon-scala

 If you need help on setting up the aspectj weaver go to http://kamon.io/introduction/get-started/ for more info. On the
 other hand, if you are sure that you do not need or do not want to use the weaver then you can disable this error message
 by changing the kamon.show-aspectj-missing-warning setting in your configuration file.


[info] c.a.s.k.l.i.LeaseCoordinator - With failover time 10000 ms and epsilon 25 ms, LeaseCoordinator will renew leases every 3308 ms, takeleases every 20050 ms, process maximum of 2147483647 leases and steal 1 lease(s) at a time.
[info] c.a.s.k.c.l.w.Worker - Initialization attempt 1
[info] c.a.s.k.c.l.w.Worker - Initializing LeaseCoordinator
[INFO] [01/05/2018 14:22:06.992] [PubSubSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [JMXExtension(akka://kamon)] Starting the Kamon(JMX) extension
[info] p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters (see <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):

    play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
    play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
    play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
    play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter

[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)[info] Updating {file:/D:/Sprint2/PubSubService/IC2287/}root...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn]  * io.netty:netty-handler:4.0.43.Final is selected over 4.0.41.Final
[warn]      +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.0.43.Final             (depends on 4.0.43.Final)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams:1.0.8    (depends on 4.0.41.Final)
[warn]  * com.google.guava:guava:22.0 is selected over {18.0, 19.0}
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.7                  (depends on 22.0)
[warn]      +- com.google.inject:guice:4.1.0                      (depends on 19.0)
[warn]      +- com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.8.1          (depends on 18.0)
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.6 is selected over 2.4.19
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-streams_2.12:2.6.7          (depends on 2.5.6)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core_2.12:10.0.10      (depends on 2.4.19)
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.6 is selected over {2.5.2, 2.4.14, 2.4.19}
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.6 ()        (depends on 2.5.6)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.7                  (depends on 2.5.6)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.12:2.5.6 ()         (depends on 2.5.6)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing_2.12:10.0.10        (depends on 2.4.19)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-jmx_2.12:0.6.7                      (depends on 2.4.14)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-core_2.12:0.6.7                     (depends on 2.4.14)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-datadog_2.12:0.6.7                  (depends on 2.4.14)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-akka-2.4_2.12:0.6.6                 (depends on 2.4.14)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-akka-2.5_2.12:0.6.7                 (depends on 2.5.2)
[warn]  * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.12:0.8.0 is selected over 0.5.0
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.6 ()         (depends on 0.8.0)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play-streams_2.12:2.6.7          (depends on 0.8.0)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.12:2.6.7                  (depends on 0.8.0)
[warn]      +- io.kamon:kamon-datadog_2.12:0.6.7                  (depends on 0.5.0)
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings

[info] Running the application with Aspectj Weaver
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 29 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to D:\Sprint2\PubSubService\IC2287\target\scala-2.12\classes ...
[info] [info] Cleaning datadir [D:\Sprint2\PubSubService\IC2287\target\scala-2.12/scoverage-data]
[info] [info] Beginning coverage instrumentation
[info] [info] Instrumentation completed [1215 statements]
[info] [info] Wrote instrumentation file [D:\Sprint2\PubSubService\IC2287\target\scala-2.12\scoverage-data\scoverage.coverage.xml]
[info] [info] Will write measurement data to [D:\Sprint2\PubSubService\IC2287\target\scala-2.12/scoverage-data]
[warn] there were two feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Done compiling.
[info] c.n.i.Application - Initiating configurations
[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[info] c.n.i.s.PubSubSupervisor - Supervisor is started
[info] c.n.i.p.a.EventRouter - EventRouter Actor is created
[info] c.n.i.u.ApplicationUtil - Checking for keys.
[info] c.n.i.t.a.TransformerActor - Transformer created.
[info] c.a.s.k.c.c.KinesisClientLibConfigurator - Value of workerId is not provided in the properties. WorkerId is automatically assigned as: 4905dbb1-2711-40c4-839c-3140086cea44
[info] c.a.s.k.c.c.KinesisClientLibConfigurator - Successfully set property initialPositionInStream with value TRIM_HORIZON
[info] c.n.i.c.KinesisConsumer -
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------- Initialising Kinesis Consumer --------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
***** Running event-publication-service-dipjyoti_akka_test *****
***** Processing Stream: dipjyoti_akka_test *****
***** WorkerId: 4905dbb1-2711-40c4-839c-3140086cea44 *****
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[info] k.Kamon$Instance - Initializing Kamon...
[INFO] [01/05/2018 14:22:06.851] [PubSubSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [DatadogExtension(akka://kamon)] Starting the Kamon(Datadog) extension
[error] k.ModuleLoaderExtension -

  ___                           _      ___   _    _                                 ___  ___ _            _
 / _ \                         | |    |_  | | |  | |                                |  \/  |(_)          (_)
/ /_\ \ ___  _ __    ___   ___ | |_     | | | |  | |  ___   __ _ __   __ ___  _ __  | .  . | _  ___  ___  _  _ __    __ _
|  _  |/ __|| '_ \  / _ \ / __|| __|    | | | |/\| | / _ \ / _` |\ \ / // _ \| '__| | |\/| || |/ __|/ __|| || '_ \  / _` |
| | | |\__ \| |_) ||  __/| (__ | |_ /\__/ / \  /\  /|  __/| (_| | \ V /|  __/| |    | |  | || |\__ \\__ \| || | | || (_| |
\_| |_/|___/| .__/  \___| \___| \__|\____/   \/  \/  \___| \__,_|  \_/  \___||_|    \_|  |_/|_||___/|___/|_||_| |_| \__, |
            | |                                                                                                      __/ |
            |_|                                                                                                     |___/

 It seems like your application was not started with the -javaagent:/path-to-aspectj-weaver.jar option but Kamon detected
 the following modules which require AspectJ to work properly:

      kamon-akka, kamon-akka-http, kamon-scala

 If you need help on setting up the aspectj weaver go to http://kamon.io/introduction/get-started/ for more info. On the
 other hand, if you are sure that you do not need or do not want to use the weaver then you can disable this error message
 by changing the kamon.show-aspectj-missing-warning setting in your configuration file.


[info] c.a.s.k.l.i.LeaseCoordinator - With failover time 10000 ms and epsilon 25 ms, LeaseCoordinator will renew leases every 3308 ms, takeleases every 20050 ms, process maximum of 2147483647 leases and steal 1 lease(s) at a time.
[info] c.a.s.k.c.l.w.Worker - Initialization attempt 1
[info] c.a.s.k.c.l.w.Worker - Initializing LeaseCoordinator
[INFO] [01/05/2018 14:22:06.992] [PubSubSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [JMXExtension(akka://kamon)] Starting the Kamon(JMX) extension
[info] p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters (see <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):

    play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
    play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
    play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
    play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter

[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is unclear about this error message?

```
It seems like your application was not started with the
  -javaagent:/path-to-aspectj-weaver.jar option
```

Add this option to your JVM command line if you want to use LTW (load-time weaving).

Comment: That ASCII art though. It confused me for a moment too. :)

Comment: Thank you replying but thats not issue with it. I tried adding -javaagent but shows same error with that banner. If you notice when I start app its show running with aspectjweaver but then again same banner.

Comment: I cannot see anything in the console output related to AspectJ weaving any classes. I guess you have a typo in your command line in the Java agent part or maybe a relative path which cannot be resolved instead of an absolute one. It is hard to tell without seeing for myself. In your case it should be something like: `-javaagent:/my/path/to/aspectjewaver-1.8.6.jar` BTW, why 1.8.6 and not 1.8.13? Could you share your command line and also your _aop.xml_, please?

Answer (score 0):

Kamon sbt aspectj runner for play 2.6 should be at version 1.1.0

> addSbtPlugin("io.kamon" % "sbt-aspectj-runner-play-2.6" % "1.1.0")